# Is it "wrong" for properties to call methods or start events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

Naming conventions imply that (typically) properties are nouns, methods are verbs. Now, I know these are guides, not rules, but it's something best to follow a guide when you can.

This means, the following

```
Person.Name = "Dave";
```

should only set the Name property. I would not expect the property to look like

```
public string Name
{ 
    set
      { 
          UpdateDatabase(value);
      }
}
```

My question is pretty much exactly the example above but in relation to DependencyProperties.

My application has a UserControl, it looks like

```
 <uc:MyControl MyControlMyValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=userControls:MyOtherControl}, Path=MyValue, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

So, as you can see in the above, when the MyControlMyValue property is updated, it updates the MyValue property. The problem I have is when this property is updated I need it to perform more logic than simple binding!

At the moment, I'm voting to ignore the guide and implement something like

```
    private double _myValue;
    public double MyValue
    {
        get { return __myValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value == __myValue)
                return;

            __myValue= value;
            LookAtMeHiddenAway();
            OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");
        }
    }
```

Is there a better approach as it does feel very wrong to me?

Comment: Reading a property should be fast. But what about writing it? You are raising an event in there, so arbitrary code could run when you set it. If that is the case anyway, what is stopping you from calling a method?

Comment: Yes @Kris, you are right but this implication is designed by Microsoft and for some reason I felt it was the only exception to the rule... I'm still new to this world (programming) and so the guides are important to me.

Comment: FYI, DependencyProperty setters/getters in your classes are NOT called when a binding is updated.  The binding system handles this at a low level, so any code you expect to run in your setters/getters won't be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it depends. 
If we are talking about general programming guideline, I would say no. Do not call methods inside properties, as I and others when we use properties (write/read) we *expect* of storing and retrieving data. So if you are going to *change* something, change it by calling a method, that manifests *by declaration* its behavior.

In case, instead, of `WPF` that *is* actually an expected behavior. So in case of `WPF` properties *are* suitable for changing data inside and *are expected* to behave in that way.

Bottom line: there are no strong restrictions on subject, but *suggested guideline* that is based on *expected behavior* of the code in the given environment.

Comment: Ah, so that would be the WinForms guy here looked at me as I committed a deadly sin when I suggested it! So, it's actually expected (accepted) to have methods inside properties in these situations. Thank you.

Comment: @DaveRook: in case of WPF , yes. Cause we bind a property and expect that it is going to change something in ModelView (if it's not readonly naturally)

Comment: @DaveRook: yes fr WindowsForms it's not so good idea, but again, if you *really need* that noone can restrict it. Those are just guides.

Answer (score 4):

I would create an event called OnMyValueChanged and anything that needs to update when that property changed would register a handler to that event. Or handle the PropertyChanged event. It's the same thing really, but it avoids putting logic in the setter that is not directly applicable to the property (eg constraining the value).